# При добавлении нового файла в проект добовляется NSObject+

Tags: xcode

При добавлении нового файла в проект добавляется “NSObject+“ перед названием самого файла, к примеру даю название для нового файла ASTest, а выходит NSObject+ASTest
[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXoQJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это потому что вы добавляете категорию а не класс. Obj-c классы можно создать через Cocoa Touch Class (iOS) или Cocoa Class (MacOS). А вы создаете Objective-C File -> Category (это реализация паттерна "Декоратор"), категории по Apple Gide називаются по шаблону "расширяемый класс + название метода"

Comment: Спасибо огромное)))